# How to select contact that fecth from API?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNQ4Y.png)I have problem with this UI. Can you assist me to create this UI?

I try but i can' custom it. please show me how to build this platform.
How to select contact that fecth from API?

```
ListView(
  children: con.contactOwnerList.map((element) {
    return Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             children: [
               Text(
                 element.name
                        .toString()
                        .toUpperCase()
                        .characters
                        .first,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                  child: ListTile(
                           leading: const CircleAvatar(),
                           title: Text('${element.name}'),
                           subtitle: Text('${element.email}'),
                           trailing: SvgPicture.asset(
                            Assets.images.svg.createCase.circleCheck),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                ),
                const Divider()
              ],
             );
   }).toList(),
),
```

Comment: i don't find any UI. please edit you question. with what you are expecting and what you got. it will be helpful.

Comment: Please kindly wait

Comment: Please click this link to see ui https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNQ4Y.png

Comment: can you share me the code that you tried.

Comment: I can't paste here, can you provide code to me.

Comment: i have been update it above.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how you `contactOwnerList` data formate. so i assume as below.

```
 List contacts = [
    {"FName": "Okhan", "LName": "kumar A1", "number": "95565654545"},
    {"FName": "Okhan", "LName": "kumar A3", "number": "95245122215"},
    {"FName": "Mr.", "LName": "Kim c1", "number": "95522502545"},
    {"FName": "Mr.", "LName": "Cassy d6", "number": "97842854545"},
    {"FName": "Mr.", "LName": "kumar t6", "number": "89565654545"},
    {"FName": "Okhan", "LName": "kumar b4", "number": "95565654505"},
    {"FName": "Okhan", "LName": "kumar c1", "number": "95522502545"},
    {"FName": "Okhan", "LName": "kumar d6", "number": "97842854545"},
    {"FName": "Okhan", "LName": "kumar f6", "number": "89565654545"},
  ];
  var currentletter = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    contacts.sort((a, b) => (b['FName']).compareTo(a['FName']));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: contacts.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print(contacts[index]['FName']);

            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Label(context, index),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                "${contacts[index]['FName'].toString()[0].toUpperCase()}${contacts[index]['LName'].toString()[0].toUpperCase()}"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "${contacts[index]['FName']}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    " ${contacts[index]['LName']}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 4),
                              Text(
                                "${contacts[index]['number']}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Label(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (contacts[index]['FName'].toString()[0].toUpperCase() != currentletter) {
      currentletter = "${contacts[index]['FName'].toString()[0].toUpperCase()}";
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          "${contacts[index]['FName'].toString()[0].toUpperCase()}",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

[image: sample output]

check this code. tweak how you want.

Comment: It's right, but I want to use ListView. How to do?

Comment: When I scroll at the end of list, It’s display wrong label.